# Found conflicts between System.Net.Http, when installing IdentityModel (3.2.0.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, identityserver4

I have a warning showing on my class library (4.7.2) when I install IdentityModel 3.2.0.0.

I already have a reference to System.Net.Http (4.3.3) via Nuget, When I install ing I now have this error:

[image]
The reference it's self looks like this:

[image]

I've tried uninstalling it and reinstalling etc.. but nothing so far.

Comment: try a look at this one seems to have some good thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866419/found-conflicts-between-system-net-http

Comment: Try switching "copy local" to false.  Also, you may have packages installed in your project that depend on other versions of this library file, have a google search for dependency bindings.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your reply's, I've tried changing it to false but I still get the warning. The only dependency that uses it is IdentityModel. I install version 4.3.3. the version referenced is 4.0.0.0 is that right?