# Why is there Build error when publishing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publishing

I know this has been answered before but they are not helpful.
So, when I'm building the program,it is succesfull. But when I publish the project I get the following multiple errors -

Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs   4   Active

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share errors as text, not as images of text. Search engines and those people with visual impairments cannot read the error text.

Comment: Including the actual text, rather than a picture of it, would be much more helpful.

Comment: Try a clean build   You are missing two references : IAdminWorker and IStoresWorker

Comment: Here is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424880/8335151) that solve "conflict issue". Besides, confirm if all the dll references have been included.

Comment: @jdweng they are not missing. Normal build works perfect. These only comes when I try to publish, however when I checked the reference they were all good.

Comment: @HereticMonkey and Martin I'll include text shortly.

Comment: Why are you building after publishing?  Publishing you run the exe file and do not open VS.