# how to fix conflict system.Net.http

Tags: azure, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Hello I try to install the todo list azure https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAzure/

when i compile i get a warning about systeme.net.http i found this about it but i do not see any web.config in my project should i create it?
[System.Net.Http version conflict causing build warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893854/system-net-http-version-conflict-causing-build-warning)

i also have 50 warning about skipping documentDBTodo.droid.Ressource...

and my preview view say an exception occurred

https://gyazo.com/058dfeac6a2561ef799e03f6e2430853

Thank you

I fixed the device.os is obsolet

i updated : 
xamarin.Forms
Microsoft.Azure.DocumenDbCore

I just want a todo list preconfigured for online server with xamarin

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  I have no idea.  You say you get a warning but don't give us the exact message.  And warning are just that, warnings.  They are not errors.  You also mention an exception in preview but don't tell us what the exact exception is.  You also don't tell us what project you're testing - iOS, Android, or UWP.  The iOS and Android projects both build successfully for me without needing to make any changes.

Comment: i dont understand why you dont have any warning :/ the conflict net says : 

Conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" were found and could not be resolved. These reference conflicts are logged in the build log when the log detail level is set to Detailed. 

i try android and I had messages from the departure

Comment: Again, this is a warning - is it actually causing a problem?  Did you look in the build log like suggested?

Comment: yes i did want to tell you that we can create a healthy solution despite all these warnings. 

because I am overwhelmed with error at the beginning of each new project I feel that it could come from my processor. as the previewer does not work I thought that it could come from the

Comment: I understood why you do not have an error. during the tutorial they advise to download the version azure thing that I did it is well configure and it adds and modifies but with some bugs. 
so i also try the one you have it does not go back warning lie you saied but does not connect the database even after the configuration in the file constant.cs where I fill in applicationUrl accountKey databaseId collectionId, so i continue with the one that connect thank you. thas already good to do thats ;)

Comment: @StanBomin Can you post your analysis as an answer so that it helps the wider community? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1>  Impossible de résoudre le conflit entre "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" et "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choix arbitraire de "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".